# Is there a keyboard shortcut to open up Outline search or Quick Outline in Visual Studio Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

Is there a keyboard shortcut to open up Quick Outline in Visual Studio Code? This is useful to go to a definition quickly.

In Eclipse it's called Quick Outline and you use Command + O to open it. There is an Outline panel in Visual Studio Code but no keyboard shortcut to navigate instantly into it's search field like you can in Eclipse.

**UPDATE:**
I'm using Find (Command + F) and it does an amazing job. It's fast too. It's only issue is it finds every occurrence in addition to definitions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Accidentally used the keyboard shortcut `Command + T` and a super search came up that supports finding definitions. This will work.

Note: Command + Shift + T is definitions in Eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

What you want is `Go to Symbol in Editor` a.k.a. `workbench.action.gotoSymbol`.

The default shortcut on Mac ist <kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>O</kbd>.
Alternatively you can use Quick Open (<kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd>) and type an `@` to start a search for symbols.

<kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd> does a `Go to Symbol in Workspace`, so searches Symbols globally.